# Why does my email method always send email with the email itself as attachment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

Trying to send email with an excel attachment with some body text.
For whatever reason, the email that I receive is always an email with the email I want to send as attachment, then the excel itself is attached to the attached email...

Is there some property to disable this behavior?

```
public void sendEmailWithAttachment(EmailProperties properties) {
    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

    try {
        message.setFrom(properties.getFrom());
        message.setHeader("X-Mailer", properties.getHeader());

        if (properties.getPriority() != null) {
            message.setHeader("X-Priority", properties.getPriority().getValue());
        }

        InternetAddress[] toEmailArray = properties.getToAddresses().toArray(new InternetAddress[properties.getToAddresses().size()]);

        message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toEmailArray);
        message.setSubject(properties.getSubject());
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(properties.getMessageText())) {
            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            mimeBodyPart.setText(properties.getMessageText());
            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
        }

        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(properties.getContents(), properties.getContentType())));
        mimeBodyPart.setFileName(properties.getFileName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        send(message);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        logger.error("Error attempting to send email!", exc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to send only the attachment or the text to check how the message is being sent? Also, just to make the code a bit easier to read, try renaming the body parts variables (eg: textBodyPart and fileBodyPart). It helps to understand the code a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, if the email contain no body text, the email sent has the email as attachment. Once there is body text, the email looked normal where it shows the body text then the excel as attachment... Just why...

Comment: What does your send method do?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: just sends the email base on some flags and logging

Comment: Details?  Is the only JavaMail API that it uses the Transport.send method?  And the debug output?  When you say "the email sent has the email as attachment", does that mean you have a message/rfc822 attachment that's another complete email message?

Comment: JavaMailSender is spring's javamail, in the end it executes 'transport.sendMessage. a pdf is attachment for email, that email is somehow turned into .iml file, which is then attached to the email i receive. from my findings, when the body is empty, it'll do that, if the body has text, itll be sent as normal email.

Comment: If you're using a Spring class to send the message, it sounds like that's where the problem is.